# left join in pandas with approximately equal numeric comparison

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using the following to do a left join in Pandas:

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=xrf_df,
                       right=statistics_and_notes_df, 
                       how='left', 
                       left_on=depth_column_name, 
                       right_on='Core Depth')
```

however the depth_column_name and 'Core Depth' columns are floating point numbers.
Is there a good way to do this left join such that the comparison is approximately equal such as np.isclose()?

Comment: This feature will be available out of the box in the next release (0.20.0) by using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) with the parameter `direction='nearest'` (can be restricted with the `tolerance` parameter).  Until then, this will likely require some custom coding.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tolerance parameter in merge_asof is an integer or TimeDelta. I would need a float like 0.003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have the following DFs:

```
In [111]: a
Out[111]:
      a  b  c
0  3.03  c  3
1  1.01  a  1
2  2.02  b  2

In [112]: b
Out[112]:
      a  x
0  1.02  Z
1  5.00  Y
2  3.04  X
```

Let's set joining float64 column as index (sorted):

```
In [113]: a = a.sort_values('a').set_index('a')

In [114]: b = b.assign(idx=b['a']).set_index('idx').sort_index()

In [115]: a
Out[115]:
      b  c
a
1.01  a  1
2.02  b  2
3.03  c  3

In [116]: b
Out[116]:
         a  x
idx
1.02  1.02  Z
3.04  3.04  X
5.00  5.00  Y
```

now we can use [DataFrame.reindex(..., method='nearest')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
In [118]: a.join(b.reindex(a.index, method='nearest'), how='left')
Out[118]:
      b  c     a  x
a
1.01  a  1  1.02  Z
2.02  b  2  1.02  Z
3.03  c  3  3.04  X

In [119]: a.join(b.reindex(a.index, method='nearest'), how='left').rename(columns={'a':'a_right'})
Out[119]:
      b  c  a_right  x
a
1.01  a  1     1.02  Z
2.02  b  2     1.02  Z
3.03  c  3     3.04  X

In [120]: a.join(b.reindex(a.index, method='nearest'), how='left').rename(columns={'a':'a_right'}).reset_index()
Out[120]:
      a  b  c  a_right  x
0  1.01  a  1     1.02  Z
1  2.02  b  2     1.02  Z
2  3.03  c  3     3.04  X
```

PS you may want to use `df.reindex(..., tolerance=<value>)` parameter in order to set the tolerance: `abs(index[indexer] - target) <= tolerance`

Comment: This works perfectly if I add the tolerance keyword to reindex.

Comment: @user90855, glad i could help :)