# Filtering data frames based on multiple parameters at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(1,5), "b": range(6, 10), "c": range(11, 15) , "d": range(15, 19)})
```

I want to filter this data frame based on the values of two columns which make up coordinate points. Say c, d are the x, and y coordinates respectively. However, I want to check if given the list of points in the data frame, which points fall within the values of a list of x coordinates and a list of y coordinates.

```
x_coord = [4,12,13,17,19]
y_coord = [16,18,25,29,32]
```

Using the "isin" function of pandas, how can I parse both the c and d columns of the data frame simultaneously and check them against the values in a list? (I want to be able to use this parsing method for large data frames)

Output wanted: data frame containing the entire row of the original data frame that has both c & d values that are in both x & y lists.

Comment: You have an R dataframe, but you ask for a pandas solution?

Comment: I will change it back to R , since the data.frame is from R

Comment: your coordinates have mismatch too . x_coord have 7 values while y_coord have only five. This is intended?

Comment: @rye_bread please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: edited with python data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new column as a tuple of the other two and using `isin` in that column as follows:

```
In[0]: df['coords'] = list(zip(df['c'], df['d']))
     : df[df['coords'].isin(zip(x_coord, y_coord))]

Out[0]:    
a  b   c   d     e
0  1  6  11  15  NaN
1  2  7  12  16  NaN
2  3  8  13  17  NaN
3  4  9  14  18  NaN
```

Or you can create a new dataframe with your coordinates and use a inner_join method to get only rows that match.

```
In[0]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(1,5), "b": range(6, 10), "c": range(11, 15) , "d": range(15, 19), "e": np.nan})

     : x_coord = range(11, 15) 
     : y_coord = range(15, 19) 

     : coords = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x_coord, y_coord)), columns=['c', 'd'])
     : df.merge(coords, on=['c', 'd'], how='inner')

Out[0]:    
    a  b   c   d     e
    0  1  6  11  15  NaN
    1  2  7  12  16  NaN
    2  3  8  13  17  NaN
    3  4  9  14  18  NaN
```

Comment: So does a merge allow me to take the column of the data frame essentially as a list and merge the two? If so does it return the values that are in both or does it contain all of the values (both list and df column)?

Comment: The merge with `how='inner'` merge the two dataframes only on rows that have same value for correspondent keys (c=x and d=y). If you know SQL, is the same logic of an *inner join*.

Comment: For visualization of sql joins: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1xlqeu/sql_joins_explained_xpost_rsql/

Comment: Could an inner join work with different decimal values? If I had values in the x and y columns that had 5 digits of precision while the values in the x/y data frame had 7 digits of precision, can inner join merge those two? For example if I had 27.12345 in the column c and then the value I want it to consider the same is any value of 27.12345xx value.

Comment: You can see an example of your question in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860259/left-join-in-pandas-with-approximately-equal-numeric-comparison

Comment: I never do that before, but I guess you can use a round function to aproximate the values.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the issue is that I do not want to approximate the numbers, I have already truncated a coordinate (x,y) to about lets say 4 values past the decimal. If I have 12.1234, 17.1234 as values from c, d respectively, and I have a values 12.1234567, 17.1234987 appear in the df I am merging with, I want that to be considered as a correct merge. However I do not want to have values close to 12.1234, just values that contain 12.1234xxx

Comment: would "isin" not work for the case that I want df's to be merged where the values are  "in" values of a lower precision?

Comment: The problem with `isin` is that you need two values at same row, c = x AND d = y. Consider the case you use two isin, one for c = x other for d = y, with the `isin` only you cannot guarantee that each return the same result set, you would need to join the index of each boolean mask, mimic the behavior of the merge.

Comment: Added a example with `isin` method which involve the creation of new column as tuple of 'c' and 'd'

Comment: would isin still work if I wanted 7.14 to be considered "in" 7.1?

Comment: The function will check if tuples are equal(have same values in it). You would need to create the tuple with the truncate version of your value first. Another aproach is implement a method which return a boolean mask (like isin) and use it to filter patterns. Your new method can check if values are almost equals to some degree.